# How does npm handle circular dependency?

Tags: npm, dependencies, npm-install

Just wondering, if there is a package with circular/cyclic dependency, does npm handle that? How? I have googled but couldn't find very useful results.

---

I can think of two kinds of problems here:

1. Circular dependency with same version: `A->B`, `B->C`, `C->A`

   Does npm build the dependency like this? (Only my guess, didn't find any circular dependency to actually test on)

   ```
   A@1.0.0
   └─┬ B@1.0.0
     └─┬ C@1.0.0
       └── A@1.0.0 (deduped)
   ```
2. Circular dependency with different version: `A@2.0.0->B`, `B->C`, `C->A@^1.0.0`, I cannot even guess what would happen if such things exist?

Comment: I dont think npm handles circular dependancies as such. I created three projects the way you mentioned and tried to do an 'npm install' on the first proect. Npm went into a recursive loop.

Comment: @AmbuSreedharan I have yet to validate your claim, but I think you can make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly discourage having cyclic package dependencies. It is not just if npm can deal with that, but all the tooling you might have around your dependencies. For example, I got some weird Typescript build errors caused by the cyclic package dependencies, npm seemed to be fine. Maybe it did not notice the cycle being inside a mono repo, but Typescript was failing and there was no clear error saying "this is failing because of a cyclic dependency"

Out of experience, I would say "cyclic dependencies" tend to be a nasty pot of problems. It is not a black vs white situation, it tends to be like "undefined behavior", sometimes OK, sometimes not so OK.

I cannot tell you if npm clearly supports cyclic dependencies, but I can tell you it is more important to consider if tools can manage cyclic npm packages. Overall it is safer to assume it is not